# Too many connections to memcached in TIME_WAIT state

Tags: tcp, memcached, time-wait

I have troubles with connections to memcached.
I assume there are no free local ports at busy hours.

netstat -n | grep "127.0.0.1" | grep TIME_WAIT | wc

This command give me 36-50k connections, possible it is more at busy hours

How could extend port range or is there other way to fix it?

Comment: You have *what* 'troubles with connections to memcached'? Why do you have to assume anything? What does the error message actually *say?*

Answer (score -1):

We have fixed it.
So if you have many connections with TIME_WAIT status (more than 10-20K) i recommend to make some changes for tcp/ip settings

1. Modify **net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout**.  We use 20s, and i think we can 15s or 10s because connections between servers are really fast.
2. Extend port range. Modify **net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range**. Set it for "1024 - 65535"

Comment: The first presents a TCP data integrity problem and the second has nothing to do with any TIME_WAIT 'problem', whatever it may have been.